# Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion .. On deployed version

Tags: asp.net, syncfusion

http://pastebin.com/5Ph3BfD3

I am getting the message
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion.Core, Version=11.4451.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=632609b4d040f6b4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have set copylocal to true in my project on each of the references

They are in my BIN folder on the local machine, the

The parser and the line on the web.config refer to different versions; can anyone tell me what I can to sort this out.

Frustrating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file is looking for a specific version of SyncFusion. Does the version number match the version of the syncfusion assembly?

If not, either get the correct assembly, or update the web config. Also see this if it is relevant: [Target non specific version of an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285758/target-non-specific-version-of-an-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

I have raised this with SYncfusion Tech support, they are going to see if they can reproduce it on Azure